# React.js/Next.js- TypeError: makeStore is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am trying to migrate my React app to Next.js, but I am having a problem with the store. I am using `configureStore` to create my store, as shown here:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { authSlice } from "./redux-slices/authSlice";
import { accountSlice } from "./redux-slices/accountSlice";
import { createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
    account: accountSlice.reducer
  }
});

export const wrapper = createWrapper(store);
```

This is the relavent code in the _app.js file (irrelevant code such as server error handling and the contents of the error boundary component have been removed):

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorMessage}>
        <IntlProvider
          locale={navigator.language}
          key={navigator.language}
          messages={messages[navigator.language]}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </IntlProvider>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

However, when I try to view the app in the browser, I get this:

> ```
> Server Error
>
> TypeError: makeStore is not a function
> ```

The call stack shows that the error occurs entirely in the node modules, and I don't see where in my code the error occurred exactly.

How do I properly set up the store using `configureStore` in Next.js?

Comment: where are you importing/declaring/invoking `makeStore`?